# Self host REST API on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Can SQL Server (ex. 2016) itself host a REST API without the need of a web server or any type of front end?

Ideally, the end goal would be to make REST calls to the database server directly bypassing any web server or API front end.

Comment: What you are proposing would mean that anybody would have your database login credentials which is a terrible idea. Thankfully sql server can't do this. It would be a huge security issue to say the least. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @seanLange Generally speaking, couldn't the REST remote client (cURL, shell script, Powershell, VBA, etc) manage a secure connection to the database like any other front end? I agree, not the ideal situation. But for the person I'm researching for, all they have to work with is their SQL Server access.

Comment: Well any of those options are not direct calls to the database that you said you want. And you would need some way to communicate with the server so you would need to place that server in the DMZ. Not a good idea for a sql server.

Comment: REST is an architecture style, not a service or client type, your calls are just HTTP and there's no such thing as making a "REST" call. You'll need a web server to accept traffic, and if an application in that web server implements a RESTful architecture then you're simply consuming a service (via HTTP) which implements a RESTful architecture.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need a little bit of application code.

Comment: I understand the above comment but in this case it does actually answer the question. It could be more robust but as simply an answer to the question posted the only possible answer is "NO".